# Pegar valores de um form post e repassar para uma tabela html

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

sou leigo em PHP e JSON, tenho esse código abaixo que está funcionando. Ele traz os valores de um `form`, porém tudo no mesmo tag PHP, gostaria de separar e colocar em uma tabela organizada, por exemplo: Nome, Preço, Quantidade, Subtotal.

Segue o código, espero que entendam, desde já agradeço muito pela força!

```html
<?php
    if(!isset($_POST["json_dados"])) die("Post não enviado.");

    $array_dados = json_decode($_POST["json_dados"]);


    $total = 0;

    foreach($array_dados as $obj)
    {
        echo 'Nome: '. $obj->nome . '<br>';
        echo 'Preço: '. $obj->preco . '<br>';   
        echo 'Quantidade: '. $obj->qtd . '<br>';        
        echo 'Subtotal: '. $obj->subtotal . '<br>'; 
        echo '<br><br>';

        $total = $total + $obj->subtotal;
    }

    echo 'Total: '.$total;
?>

<table width="95%"  border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td width="26%"><div align="center">Nome</div></td>
        <td width="41%"><div align="center">Preco</div></td>
        <td width="33%"><div align="center">Quantidade</div></td>
        <td width="33%"><div align="center">Subtotal</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Coloca o php dentro da tag table após a tr do cabeçalho gerando outro tr dentro do loop e td para cada informação. Aí para cada loop que ele der você terá uma nova linha.

Comment: Vou testar aqui

Comment: coloquei mais nada depois da tr

Comment: Era pra tabela ser depois disso    foreach($array_dados as $obj){ mais da erro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pontuei +1 para o lvcs, mas posto tb aqui outra resposta visto que o seu json tem um array de objetos e chamá-los como array dará um erro, pois propriedade de objeto tem que ser chamadas com setinha ( -> ).

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST["json_dados"])) die("Post não enviado.");
$array_dados = json_decode($_POST["json_dados"]);

$total = 0;

// CABEÇALHO
echo '
  <table width="95%"  border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td width="26%"><div align="center">Nome</div></td>
      <td width="41%"><div align="center">Preco</div></td>
      <td width="33%"><div align="center">Quantidade</div></td>
    <td width="33%"><div align="center">Subtotal</div></td>
    </tr>';

foreach($array_dados as $obj)
{

 echo '
    <tr>
      <td><div align="center">'. $obj->nome . '</div></td>
      <td><div align="center">'. $obj->preco . '</div></td>
      <td><div align="center">'. $obj->qtd . '</div></td>
      <td><div align="center">'. $obj->subtotal . '</div></td>
    </tr>';

    $total = $total + $obj->subtotal;
}

echo '
    <tr><td colspan="4"><div align="center">Total: '.$total.'</div></td></tr>
  </table>';

?>
```

Comment: Top meu inoxidável deu certo

Answer (score 1):

Assim deve dar:

```
<?php

//if(!isset($_POST["json_dados"])) die("Post não enviado.");


//$array_dados = json_decode($_POST["json_dados"]);

$array_dados = [
    ['nome' => "notebook", 'preco' => "999", 'qtd' => "12", 'subtotal' => "1281" ],
    ['nome' => "tv",       'preco' => "800", 'qtd' => "13", 'subtotal' => "343"  ],
    ['nome' => "teclado",  'preco' => "30",  'qtd' => "11", 'subtotal' => "50"   ],
];

$total = 0;

?>
  <table width="95%"  border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td width="26%"><div align="center"><strong>Nome</strong></div></td>
      <td width="41%"><div align="center"><strong>Preco</strong></div></td>
      <td width="33%"><div align="center"><strong>Quantidade</strong></div></td>
      <td width="33%"><div align="center"><strong>Subtotal</strong></div></td>
    </tr>

    <?php foreach($array_dados as $dado): ?>
            <tr>
              <td width="26%"><div align="center"><?php echo $dado['nome'] ?></div></td>
              <td width="41%"><div align="center"><?php echo $dado['preco'] ?></div></td>
              <td width="33%"><div align="center"><?php echo $dado['qtd'] ?></div></td>
              <td width="33%"><div align="center"><?php echo $dado['subtotal'] ?></div></td>
            </tr>

            <?php $total += $dado['subtotal']; ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </table>

  <?php echo 'Total: '.$total; ?>
```

**P.S:** Declarei um *array* no `PHP` apenas para simular o seu *json*.

Basicamente movi o `foreach` para o meio da tabela, e pra cada elemento dele coloquei uma linha, com colunas dando `echo` naquele elemento do *array*.

Deve-se alterar todo o `$dado['xxx']` por `$dado->xxx`, ou então colocar seu *json* em *array* associativo colocando `$array_dados = json_decode($_POST["json_dados"], true);`.

Comment: Precisa incrementar o valor de $total na sua resposta, somando os subtotais.

Comment: @AntonioAlexandreAlonsodeSi valeu pelo aviso, vou arrumar

Comment: Desculpe amigo nao deu certo esta vindo esses valores  ['nome' => "notebook", 'preco' => "999", 'qtd' => "12", 'subtotal' => "1281" ],

Comment: @HemersonPrestes estava alterando agora só colocando lembrete que deveria trocar por exemplo `$dado['xxx']` por `$dado->xxx` ou então usar `$array_dados = json_decode($_POST["json_dados"], true);`